# Using a hint/information-bar like the trasformations are using

Tags: python, scripting, interface, operator

The transformation-operators of blender are showing some hints/informations on the header of the 3D-View. This hints/informations are replacing the default layout-elements of the header (`template_header()`, `VIEW3D_MT_editor_menus`, `template_header_3D()`, …). I want to use this bar in my operators. But i can't find any information about this bar.

Does someone know how to uses this bar?
If not: Does someone know how this bar is named, so that i maybe can find the solution in the startup-scripts / blender c-code?

I might could prepend a very long label to `VIEW3D_HT_header` and remove it after executing/aborting the operator. But this seams to me like a messy workaround.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do this by using [Area.header_text_set()](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_78a_release/bpy.types.Area.html?highlight=header_text_set#bpy.types.Area.header_text_set)

Here is an example using the Modal Operator template:

```
import bpy
from bpy.props import IntProperty, FloatProperty

class ModalOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Move an object with the mouse, example"""
    bl_idname = "object.modal_operator"
    bl_label = "Simple Modal Operator"

    first_mouse_x = IntProperty()
    first_value = FloatProperty()

    def modal(self, context, event):
        context.area.header_text_set("Well see? Its working...") #add text to header
        if event.type == 'MOUSEMOVE':
            delta = self.first_mouse_x - event.mouse_x
            context.object.location.x = self.first_value + delta * 0.01

        elif event.type == 'LEFTMOUSE':            
            context.area.header_text_set() #on confirm restore header to default
            return {'FINISHED'}

        elif event.type in {'RIGHTMOUSE', 'ESC'}:
            context.object.location.x = self.first_value
            context.area.header_text_set() #on exit restore header to default
            return {'CANCELLED'}

        return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        if context.object:
            self.first_mouse_x = event.mouse_x
            self.first_value = context.object.location.x

            context.window_manager.modal_handler_add(self)
            return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}
        else:
            self.report({'WARNING'}, "No active object, could not finish")
            return {'CANCELLED'}    

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(ModalOperator)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(ModalOperator)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Note that using `header_text_set` without an argument restores the header to default.